# Extract row in a double matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a double matrix as a data frame `V` in R that looks like this:

```
row.names id1 id2 id3
id1        0   2   4
id2        1   0   3     
id3        5   1   0
...
```

how can I extract the row where `row.names` = id2?

I tried the following:

```
id2_row<-V[V[,1]=='id2',]
```

It is not working. Is it because I have a double matrix? My understanding is that a double matrix is not numeric, therefore I can't do the following: `V[V[,1]=='id2',]`. Is this correct?

Comment: If that is a numeric matrix, there can be no header for the rownames. Provide `dput(V)`.

Comment: Is it really a `matrix` or is it a `data.frame`? btw what do you mean with "double matrix"?

Comment: it is a data.frame. As for double matrix, it says in R that my `V` matrix is a 4127*4127 double matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate some Data

```
m <- matrix(c(0, 1, 5, 2, 0, 1, 4, 3, 0), nrow = 3)
df <- as.data.frame(m)
row.names(df) <- c("id1", "id2", "id3")
```

Subsetting a `data.frame` and keeping it's names

```
with_names <- df[2,]

# 1)
print(with_names)
##    V1 V2 V3
##id2  1  0  3

# 2)
df[row.names(df) == "id2" , ]
##    V1 V2 V3
##id2  1  0  3
```

FYI: This is another option to subset `data.frames`. I add it for completeness.

```
df[2, , drop = TRUE]
```

Subsetting a `data.table`. 
There are no row.names but subsetting works even faster.

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(m)
print(DT)
setkey(DT, V1, V2, V3)
print(DT)
DT[2]
```

Subsetting a `matrix`. You can again subset the row you nedd, but you won't get any names.

```
class(m)
## [1] "matrix"

# Method 1)
m[2,]
## [1] 1 0 3

# Method 2)
ind <- matrix(c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3), nrow = 3)
m[ind]
identical(m[2,], m[ind])
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I believe you could benefit a lot from reading [an introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. Thanks for the link also. I started in R yesterday so yes a lot reading is needed. I will try to find a way to extract the row but also keeping the column names.

Comment: Well I thought op just wanted `V["id2",]`, since he says that V is a data frame.

Comment: you are right! I read matrix and answered for it. But i've edited the answer to include dataframes. He actually wants the id2 row.      ```id2  1   0   3```

Comment: It was apparently useful to the OP but IMHO, if you are not using `"id2"` anywhere, you are kind of missing the question. To assume that `"id2"` is in row `2` is a (likely) dangerous shortcut.

Comment: @flodel i've edited the answer so it's clearer and conected to OP description. There are some extra details, as i think he needed to learn how to subset. The reference to ```"id2"``` i believe was used to define clearly what he wanted. i.e. subsetting the second row.

Answer (score 2):

This is R, so there are many possibilities. The best approach depends on what V really is and what you want `id2_row` to be.

If V is a numeric matrix then you could try `V["id2", ]` or

```
id2_row <- V[rownames(V) == "id2", ]
```

If V is a dataframe and id2 is a row name then the same works: `V["id2", ]` or

```
id2_row <- V[rownames(V) == "id2", ]
```

If V is a dataframe and `row.names` is a column of V then what you suggest should work, or equivalently

```
id2_row <- V[V$row.names == "id2", ]
```

Comment: These three lines of codes have been very useful. Now I see the difference!